# unable to initiate port forwarding with ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, tunnel, openssh

I start sshd on 192.168.1.8 with the following:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
```

I then try to open an SSH tunnel to 192.168.1.5:1234 and am unable to do so. Here's what `sshd -ddd` says:

```
debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm direct-tcpip
debug3: channel 1: waiting for connection
debug1: channel 1: connected to 192.168.1.5 port 1234
debug2: channel 1: read<=0 rd 10 len 0
debug2: channel 1: read failed
debug2: channel 1: close_read
debug2: channel 1: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: direct-tcpip, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 server-session (t4 r256 i0/0 o0/0 fd 11/9 cc -1)
  #1 direct-tcpip (t4 r257 i3/0 o3/0 fd 10/10 cc -1)
```

So it's able to connect but the read is failing. And yet I'm able to connect (with no failing reads) when I do this (on 192.168.1.8):

```
ssh -p 1234 username@192.168.1.5
```

So why is the tunnel failing on 192.168.1.8 when the direct ssh connection on 192.168.1.8 isn't?

I'm using PuTTY to create the tunnel.

Comment: what is the exact command you type when you "open an SSH tunnel"?

Comment: I'm using PuTTY to dynamically create the tunnel on-demand. PuTTY creates a SOCKS5 server that I send requests to and read responses from. I then use a PHP script I wrote to connect to the SOCKS5 server, which in turn, tells PuTTY to request the tunnel. And PuTTY is creating the tunnel, as demonstrated above. I can successfully create tunnel's to google.com:80 and am able to send an HTTP request and read the response but not so for 192.168.1.5:1234. At minimum I should be getting the SSH server identifier (SSH-2.0-whatever) but I'm not.

Comment: Do you have enabled forwarding enabled on server? SOCKS proxy is Dynamic forwarding. Did you choose that one?

Comment: I checked off dynamic forwarding in PuTTY per http://superuser.com/q/983503/172193 . As for whether or not it's enabled on the server...  well, if I tell the SOCKS5 proxy to open a connection to google.com and then send an HTTP request I get a response. So it seems like it's enabled. When I do `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config` and do `/Forward` the only thing I see is `X11Forwarding yes`. I don't see `AllowTcpForwarding` but maybe that's a client only setting..